# .txt PHP File upload txt extension?

Tags: php, html, upload, filter, text-files

I am doing a file upload in php. Is .txt a valid extension to upload filters? If so may I see an example?

EDIT: I'm sorry I'm not too clear. What I mean is I only want the user to be able to upload .txt files and that is all.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything's valid until you make it invalid when it comes to uploading files. Play with this code and you'll see what properties make PHP's file processing tick:

**upload.html**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Upload a File</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="file">Filename:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 

      <br />

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**upload_file.php**:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

I'm not really sure what you're asking, so a bit clarification would be nice.

---

I don't work with PHP (Python FTW), but if you want to make sure only text files get through, filter them:

```
if ($_FILE['file']['type'] == 'text/plain' && strrpos($_FILE['file']['name'], '.txt') === strlen($_FILE['file']['name']) - strlen('.txt'))
{
  echo 'Your file is legit. Continue...'
} else {
  echo 'You can\'t upload that!'
}
```

I'm not sure if the `text/plain` will cause false-negatives, so if it does, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, unless you're using a 3rd-party library of some sorts, any file can be uploaded.  What you do with it, parsing it, is another story :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the supplied filename from your form, you must extract the file extension. You then compare the file extension to a list of extensions (that you allow) and if it does not match any of them, do not process the file.

First extract the extension by

```
$ext = substr(strrchr($file_name,'.'),1);
```

and compare the result using a case statement or (since you have 1 allowed extension) just if

```
if ($ext == 'txt') // upload the file
```